# How to convert semicolon separated word into array

Tags: javascript

I am getting some values like

this is in the loop

```
myArr[i].value = ["US"];
myArr[i+1].value = ["US";"UK"]
```

so when I am breaking that

```
value1 = myArr[i].value[0]
value2 = myArr[i+1].value[0]
```

I am getting values like this

```
value1 = "US"
value2 = "US;UK"
```

I want my value1 and value2 into an array

output :

```
value1 = ["US"];
value2[0] = ["US"]
value2[1] = ["UK"]
```

Here is what I am trying.

```
var myVAl = mySourceValue[i].value;
    newVal = myVAl[0];
    newVal = newVal.split(";");
```

Here newVal is coming as ["US;UK"]. But I need as into seperate array. Also it is failing when there is no ";". For only one value.
[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: `myArr[i+1].value = ["US";"UK"]` is invalid. Array items are not separated by semicolon.

Comment: fix it. `myArr[i+1].value = ["US","UK"]`

Comment: consider changing your array separator by using a comma `,` instead of a semicolon `;`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Exactly, even I was wondering. I attach screenshot. Please check.

Comment: var array = string.split(';');

Comment: The screenshot shows `["US;UK"]`, not `["US";"UK"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here newVal is coming as ["US;UK"]. But I need as into seperate array.

You already have

```
myArr[i+1].value[0] // as "US:UK"
```

So just split this to get your array

```
var value = myArr[i+1].value[0];
var newValArr = value.indexOf( ";" ) != -1 ? value.split( ";" ) : value;
```

Comment: What if there is only one value.

Comment: @David In that case you will get an array with only one value. Do you need it to be done differently?

Comment: But I need to check then weather `myArr[i].value[0]` will be having `;` value or noot

Comment: your answer in partially correct. For multiple value I am getting an array but for single value I am getting as a string. even the same issue I had with my code. And ya thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @David I added the logic to keep this as string in case there is no semicolon because you mentioned in your comment *But I need to check then weather myArr[i].value[0] will be having ; value or noot*. If this is not required, you can simply remove the check.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider below solution as well

```js
var array = new Array(); 
array = "[US;UK]".replace(";",",").replace("[","").replace("]","").split(',');
alert(array[0]);
alert(array[1]);
```